# Changes to Joomla live site

Tags: joomla

Is it possible to make changes on a Joomla live site,without making it offline or interrupting users?

There is going to be added a new feature, but I wonder if it is possible to do while it's live.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what type of functionality you are trying to block.  If it is something controlled within a module or menu item, you can set access to special and then login to the front as an admin to see.
If it is within the PHP, you can wrap it in a conditional checking the user's access level.